# opencv 3.2.0 eclipse imgcodecs.hpp

Tags: eclipse, opencv

when I'm running cloning_demo.cpp from opencv 3.2.0 example/samples I get an error :

> fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory, while the error occurs at line:
>   **#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"**

while the other lines are executed without errors.
For example (#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp)

Also I would like to emphasize, that when I run it thourgh the command line (cmake), there is no errors.

Comment: I guess your ide can't find the file. Check of you provided the correct include directories.

Comment: I add the include libraries  form  **pkg-config --cflags opencv** as well the libraies from   **pkg-config --libs opencv**   to the linker . If I guess right the imgcodecs is **not** in my  pkg-config --libs opencv like  core.hpp or highgui.hpp